# The same TFS Build Definition is different for different developers

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, build-definition

We're moving our projects to visualstudio.com and it works fine.

I've created some build definitions and changed some default settings. I used Visual Studio 2015 to create and edit the build definitions.

My colleagues can not see all the changes I've made when they view the build definitions on their machines in Visual Studio 2015 and vice versa. Some settings are not updated.

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Do they click refresh button after you update the build definitions? Can you share a screenshot for the difference?

Comment: Are you using  the new  build system or the legacy xaml builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem started when we migrated from TFS2010 to VSO.

We're using the legacy xaml build definitions where we eventually found the problem:

Some setting values were enclosed in sharp brackets [] in the xaml.

Removing the sharp brackets solved it. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue during our migration from TFS 2010 to 2015.  In the end we found two causes for this:

- Users were pointed at the wrong TFS server

[image]

- Users needed to refresh the TFS data in VS

[image]